# What is alternative before ES6 of getter method existing in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter, es5-shim

Getter method in ES6 is defined as METHOD & called as ATTRIBUTE  (calling `obj.method` instead of `obj.method(..)`)

Example :

```
class Job  {
    constructor(){
        this.start=new Date();
    }

    get age(){
        return new Date()-this.start;
    }
}
```

then:

```
var vm=new Job();
//....
vm.age // call Getter method
```

My question is: What is the alternative to that before ES6, if any?

Comment: Not a method, and not *called as ATTRIBUTE*, but rather, "referred to as property".

Comment: @torazaburo: You removed too much whitespace ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since ES5 you have been able to define getters and setters using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Your ES6 code is essentially syntactic sugar for the following ES5 code:

```
function Job ( ) {
    this.start = new Date;
}

Object.defineProperty( Job.prototype, 'age', {
  get: function ( ) { return new Date - this.start; }
} );
```

Before that some engines had non-standard support for getters, such as [Object.prototype.__defineGetter__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__), which would've be used like this to replicate your functionality:

```
Job.prototype.__defineGetter__( 'age', function ( ) {
  return new Date - this.start;
} );
```

SpiderMonkey also had some other ways to do it even earlier:

```
Job.prototype.age getter = function() {
    return new Date - this.start;
};

// or, this one, which declares age as a variable in the local scope that acts like a getter

getter function age() { ... };
```

None of those ways should be used today, except for `Object.defineProperty` which is still very useful in ES6.

Comment: And the syntax was available on object literals in ES5 too!

Answer (score 3):

Since ES5 each property of an object has a Getter and Setter functions.
You can find the full documentation here: [MDN - Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

When you create an object you can then define a new property and tell which functions to use when getting and setting that value:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty( obj, 'propName', {
  get: function() { return 42; },
  set: function(newValue){ this.propName = newValue; }
});
```

In your ES6 code what you're doing is defining a new constructor function and then defining the `get`ter for the `age`.